# I would like help calculating the probability of a simple problem

Tags: probability

It's been a while since I've taken stat class so I would like help solving this problem.

If the probability of a event occurring, like a person falling when they take a step, is 0.001%, then what is the probability of that person falling at least twice in a row in 1000 steps?

Then what is the probability if 1 million people take 10 thousand steps that at least one person falls at least twice in a row?

Comment: Solving this will require some thought about your assumptions. It is plausible that after falling on one step, a person's chance of falling on the next step might increase. To address that you will need to assume some quantitative relationship--or have data.  On the other hand, perhaps this question is just a metaphor for some other kind of event in which the probabilities are *independent.*  Which interpretation do you need addressed?

Comment: The probabilities are independent. I tried to come up with a scenario that would help explain the problem but I failed to think about a possible correlation of a person falling and then possibly falling again because they just fell.  Nice catch.  Just insert X and Y where needed, :-)

Comment: Good, thank you! The answer to this simple problem might surprise you: when the chance of a fall is $p$ and $n$ steps are taken, the chance of at least two falls in a row equals $\frac{2^{-n-1} \left((p+1) \left(-p-\sqrt{(2-3 p)
   p+1}+1\right)^n-\sqrt{(2-3 p) p+1} \left(-p-\sqrt{(2-3 p)
   p+1}+1\right)^n-(p+1) \left(-p+\sqrt{(2-3 p)
   p+1}+1\right)^n-\sqrt{(2-3 p) p+1} \left(-p+\sqrt{(2-3 p)
   p+1}+1\right)^n+2^{n+1} \sqrt{(2-3 p) p+1}\right)}{\sqrt{(2-3 p) p+1}}$ and this is one of the simplest ways to write it!

Comment: All I can say it wow and I'm going to have all sorts of problems remembering the solution when I want to play stump my friends at a dinner party.  I figured it was slightly more complex the the standard "only 2 times" problems but didn't realize it was that complex.  So for all practical purposes is the solution below in user2015762's answer correct?

Answer (score 3):

How would you keep track of the person's walk?  All you need to do is (1) remember whether their previous step was a fall or not and (2) note when two falls occur in a row.  That is a data structure with three *states*:

1. Previous step was not a fall.
2. Previous step was a fall.
3. At some point in the past, two steps in a row were falls.

Each step in the walk is a random *transition* between states.  The new state is determined entirely by whether the next step is a fall (with probability $p$) or not (with complementary probability $1-p$).  Of course once state (3) is entered it doesn't really matter what the next step is: you stay in state (3) with probability $1$).

This information can be summarized with a *transition matrix* $\mathbb{Q}$ whose rows and columns index the states.  Row $i$ lists the transition probabilities from state $i$ into the other states.

$$\mathbb{Q} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1-p & p & 0 \\
 1-p & 0 & p \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

The same information can also be neatly drawn with a graph having one node for each state and directed edges denoting the transitions.  The edge labels give the transition probabilities:

[image: Figure]

---

There are several ways to calculate with this information.  The machinery of linear algebra shows how to compute powers of $\mathbb{Q}$ and extract the answers from their coefficients.  A more elementary approach exploits the inherent recursive nature of this system.  Let $f(n,p,i)$ be the chance of reaching state (3) (two falls in a row) within $n$ steps beginning at state $i$. The first part of the question asks for $f(n,p,1)$ (with $n=1000$ and $p=10^{-5}$). The graph tells us

1. $f(n,p,3) = 1$ because we are already in state (3).
2. $f(n,p,2) = (1-p) f(n-1,p,1) + p f(n-1,p,3)$ because from state (2) transitions are possible to state (1) (with probability $1-p$) and to state (3) (with probability $p$).
3. $f(n,p,1) = (1-p) f(n-1,p,1) + p f(n-1,p,2)$ for comparable reasons.

These can be combined by solving for $f(n,p,1)$ in terms of $f(n^\prime,p,1)$ for smaller values of $n^\prime$.  To abbreviate the notation let $f(n) = f(n,p,1)$:

$$f(n) = p^2 + (1-p)f(n-1) + p(1-p)f(n-2).$$

If you were to work this out manually, you would begin with a list of the known values of $f$ for $n=0,1$: $$0, 0, \ldots$$  Then you would augment this list using the recurrence relation $f(2) = p^2 + (1-p) f(1) + p(1-p) f(0) = p^2$, producing $$0, 0, p^2, \ldots$$  At the next step $f(3) = p^2 + (1-p) f(2) + p(1-p)f(0) = p^2 + (1-p)p^2 = 2p^2 - p^3$, extending the list to $0,0,p^2, 2p^2-p^3,\ldots$.  This straightforward and fast method will enable you to compute values of $f$ for small $n$ with no trouble, as illustrated with this `R` code:

```r
f <- function(n, p=10^-5, x=double(0)) {
  y <- x
  if (length(y) < 2) y <- c(0,0,NA)
  if (length(y) <= n) y <- c(y, rep(NA, 2^ceiling(log(n+1,2))-length(y)))
  i <- which.max(is.na(y))
  if (i <= n+1) for (j in i:(n+1)) y[j] <- p^2 + (1-p)*y[j-1] + p*(1-p)*y[j-2]
  return (list(f=y[n+1], cache=y))
}
f(1000, 10^(-5))$f
```

The output of `9.9899e-08` was produced in less than $0.006$ seconds on this machine.

---

A little analysis will take us a lot further.

This *inhomogeneous linear difference equation* for $f$ is a slight generalization of the Fibonacci numbers $F_n$, which satisfy $F_{n} = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ (as if the constants $1-p$ and $p(1-p)$ were both replaced by $1$ and $p^2$ were replaced by $0$ in the equation for $f(n)$.)  We may thereby emulate the well-known analyses of the Fibonacci numbers by using either linear algebra (applied to $\mathbb{Q}$) or combinatorial methods (for the linear difference equation) to obtain a closed-form solution--based on the initial conditions $f(0)=f(1)=0$--as

$$f(n) = 1-\frac{(d+p+1) \phi_{+}^n-(-d+p+1) \phi_{-}^n}{2 d}$$

where

$d = \sqrt{(1-p)^2 - 4p(1-p)} = \sqrt{1 + (2-3p)p}$

$\phi_{+} = (1-p+d)/2,\ \phi_{-} = (1-p-d)/2.$

Because $0\le p\le 1$, $\phi_{-}$ will be negative and $\phi_{+}$ will be positive (but less than $1$) and larger than $\phi_{-}$ in size.  Indeed, with smallish values of $p$, $\phi_{-}$ will be close to $0$ and $\phi_{+}$ close to $1$.  Thus, even for small $n$, $\phi_{-}^n$ can be treated as approximately zero. When that term is neglected we obtain

$$f(n) \approx  1-\frac{(d+p+1) \phi_{+}^n}{2 d}.$$

As an example of the utility of this expression, suppose $p=1/2$.  Then $d = \sqrt{1 + (2-3/2)/2} = \sqrt{5}/2$ and $\phi_{+} = (1+\sqrt{5})/4.$  The approximate formula works out to

$$f(n) \approx 1 - 1.17082 (0.809017)^n.$$

The first few values are

$$-0.2, 0.05, 0.23, 0.380, 0.498, 0.5942, 0.6717, 0.7344, 0.78514, 0.826176, 0.859374, \ldots$$

while the correct values are

$$0.0, 0.00, 0.25, 0.375, 0.500, 0.5938, 0.6719, 0.7344, 0.78515, 0.826172, 0.859375, \ldots$$

The approximation rapidly improves as $n$ grows.